# How can I monitor AWS cloudwatch customized metric on datadog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, datadog

I am using datadog for monitoring my services on AWS. On my python application, I use below code to send a data to a metric on Cloudwatch:

```
aws.put_metric_data(Namespace='Org/Test', MetricData=[{
            'MetricName': 'Failure', 'Value': 1}])
```

I can see this data on Cloudwatch -> Metric. But I don't know how I can create a monitor on Datadog to listen on this metric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell Datadog to pull custom metric. Go to AWS integrations configuration page (Integrations side menu -> Integrations -> Amazon Web Services).

You will see a list of services to integrate with, custom metrics is the last option on list. Make sure it's ticked. Takes a while for Datadog to actually start pulling the metric.

[image]

Comment: Is it billed like a datadog custom metric ?

Comment: In my testing, We enable it and need to wait for a while(more minutes) to see the metric on CloudWatch
The metric name will have a form  like that
custom metric.[YOUR_CUSTOM_METRIC_NAME]